# Value map with JQ

Tags: json, jq

I've a large JSON file where I'd like to transform some values based on some kind of mapping.

The data I have looks like:

```
[
    {"id":1, "value":"yes"},
    {"id":2, "value":"no"},
    {"id":3, "value":"maybe"}
]
```

And I'd like to transform that into a list like this:

```
[
    {"id":1, "value":"10"},
    {"id":2, "value":"0"},
    {"id":3, "value":"5"}
]
```

With the fixed mapping:

```
yes => 10
no => 0
maybe => 5
```

My current solution is based on a simple `if-elif-else` combination like this:

```
cat data.json| jq '.data[] | .value = (if .value == "yes" then "10" elif .value == "maybe" then "5"  else "0" end)'
```

But this is really ugly and I'd love to have a more direct way to express the mapping.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If one wants to avoid having to specify the mapping on the command line, then the following two variants may be of interest.

The first variant can be used with jq 1.3, jq 1.4 and jq 1.5:

```
def mapping: {"yes":"10","no":"0","maybe":"5"};
map(.value |=  mapping[.])
```

The next variant uses the --argfile option (available since jq 1.4), and is of interest if the mapping object is available in a file:

```
jq --argfile mapping mapping.jq 'map(.value |= $mapping[.])' data.json
```

Finally, in jq 1.5, other alternatives based on *import* are also available (!).

Comment: If instead of a JSON array your input is a set of lines, each one being a JSON object, could you still use this mapping technique somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution which uses an "inline" object since the mapping is small:

```
map(.value = {"yes":"10","no":"0","maybe":"5"}[.value])
```

which can be shorted with `|=` as in [peak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997358/peak)'s solution to:

```
map(.value |= {"yes":"10","no":"0","maybe":"5"}[.])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're translating string values, you should be able to use a json object to hold the mappings.  Then mapping would be trivial.

```
$ jq --arg mapping '{"yes":"10","no":"0","maybe":"5"}'
    'map(.value |= ($mapping | fromjson)[.])' data.json
```

Comment: Note that, on recent jq builds, you can use `--argjson` instead of `--arg` as to omit the `| fromjson` instruction in the script.