# Use value mapping in raw JSON lines

Tags: json, jq, logfile, recode

When input is a JSON array, it's possible to use `map` to convert values of element properties, such as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45887356/1226020.

But in my case I have raw lines of JSON objects as input, not a JSON array, and I want to convert values in each object.

Example input

```
{"level": 20, "msg": "Debug message"}
{"level": 30, "msg": "Info message"}
{"level": 30, "msg": "Info message"}
{"level": 40, "msg": "Warn message"}
{"level": 20, "msg": "Debug message"}
```

I currently do this:

```
cat test.log  | jq -rR 'fromjson? | "[\(.level)] \(.msg)"'
```

Which gives this:

```
[20] Debug message
[30] Info message
[30] Info message
[40] Warn message
[20] Debug message
```

Desired output, after some transforming etc:

```
[debug] Debug message
[info] Info message
[info] Info message
[warn] Warn message
[debug] Debug message
```

Is it possible to in JQ transform "enum" values like this?

Comment: Although it’s true that you can view your input as “raw” text, it can (and probably should) be viewed as a stream of JSON texts, which can be processed by jq as such, e.g. using `inputs` with the -n command-line option.

Comment: @peak I think the idea here is that the log might be "dirty" and contain some lines that aren't well-formed JSON. `inputs` will error the first time it sees one of those, but using `-R` and `fromjson?` will ignore those lines.

Comment: @hobbs - What you say about ? is of course true, but I was going by what the OP wrote: `raw lines of JSON objects`.

Comment: @peak yeah, maybe I assumed something more sophisticated than is going on. It's something I could imagine needing for myself, though :)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can just use `as` to declare a mapping object up front, and use it later:

```
jq -rR '{"20": "debug", "30": "info", "40": "warn"} as $levelmap
    | fromjson? | "[\($levelmap[.level | tostring])] \(.msg)"'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could still use the `inputs` expression and generate the output desired

```
jq -nr 'inputs | (.msg | split(" ")) as $m | "[\($m[0] | ascii_downcase))] \(.msg)"'
```

or if the contents of `.msg` are just an abstraction and you wanted to do a mapping of log levels, you could do

```
jq -nr --argjson levelMap '{"20": "debug", "30": "info", "40": "warn"}' 'inputs 
     | "[\($levelMap[.level | tostring])] \(.msg)"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the input is a JSON stream, then so long as the mapping from .level to the first word of the .msg is consistent, you could go with:

```
< test.log 'jq -sr '
 . as $in
 | INDEX($in[]; .level|tostring)  as $dict
 | ($dict | map_values( . = (.msg | ascii_downcase | sub(" .*";"")))) as $kw
 | $in[]
 | .level |= $kw[tostring]
 | "[\(.level)] \(.msg)"
'
```

Comment: I don't think the message is actually `Debug message`.